# Adding Action to Page not Extending Original PXObject

Tags: acumatica

I developed a page based off of default DACs from Acumatica, however it is not a a graph extension. The page itself is headed by BAccount. I am attempting to add an action to the page, but I can't seem to get it to appear. Here is my code for the action:

```
public class CustomerSpecification : PXGraph<CustomerSpecification>
{
    public PXFirst<BAccount> First;
    public PXPrevious<BAccount> Previous;
    public PXNext<BAccount> Next;
    public PXLast<BAccount> Last;
    public PXSave<BAccount> Save;

    public PXSelect<BAccount> Document;
...
    PXAction<BAccount> assignDefaultSpec;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName ="Set Default Spec")]
    [PXButton]
    protected virtual void AssignDefaultSpec()
    {
        CurrentDocument.Ask("Test", MessageButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

I included the structure of the class to give you an idea on what I am doing. I need the action to appear so that I can execute some code to set data that I need to set before the user saves and updates the database.

Any ideas on how to get the action to appear on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your graph's constructor and add the new action.

```
public CustomerSpecification()
{
    this.Actions.Add("AssignDefaultSpec", assignDefaultSpec);
}
```

Also make sure your PXAction is **public**:

```
public PXAction<BAccount> assignDefaultSpec;
```

Please notice that you are calling **CurrentDocument** on your Action but this dataview is not declared on your Graph.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. CurrentDocument is declared, I just didn't include it in the code. It is hidden as part of the ellipses.

Comment: Update: I tried what you wrote, but it seems like this.Actions.Add() requires two objects: object key, object value. Which one would I use for the assignDefaultSpec object and what would I put into the other object? Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer above, since we are adding a PXAction to a PXActionCollection, you can pass the key/name for that action on the Collection. See above. Also make sure you PXAction is public (Ex. : public PXAction<BAccount> assignDefaultSpec;)

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes and it worked. Thanks for catching that I didn't set my action's access level!